# Search the Text Content of Pages Linked from Current Page

Tags: google-chrome, search, links

This is the exact tool I am looking for: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/search-search-content-linked-current-web-page/ but it appears to no longer exist, and I can't find anything else like it.

In short, I want to be able to search for a specific word that appears in the text content (not the URL) of several (out of hundreds) of links on a page.

Anyone know of anything or know how tricky it would be to build from scratch without programming?

Thanks!
Toby

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
cd "$(mktemp -d)"
wget -r --span-hosts --level=1 <url>
grep -r "<search term>" .
```

(you might also need `-e robots=off` if some of the linked sites disallow crawling, although at the same time, it might be a bad idea to attempt anyway)

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. I'm sure this does what I'm looking for but I'm not a linux user. Anyone know of a way to do it within Chrome (possibly with Windows cmd line?)?

Comment: Heh, you didn't specify a platform :) You can use a [wget build for windows](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/). There are also [windows grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) although many programs could search for a word in local files.

Comment: Hope it works for your use case :)